# How to stack bar from data with x and y in Chart JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to plot a stack bar with data having the x and y values, eg `{x: 1, y:1}`.
But it seems that Chart JS follows indexing of array passed in the `data` with the index in the `labels` not the `x`.
I also tried using `ticks: {source: 'data'}` but no use.

I had to uncomment the `labels:` on and add index 1 and 2 in Africa dataset to see desired results.

Is there some way?

```
<canvas id="barchart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("barchart").getContext('2d');
var barchart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
    //labels: [0,1,2,3],
        datasets: [{ 
            data: [{x: 0, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 1}],
            label: "Africa",
            backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false
          }, { 
            data: [{x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 1}, {x: 3, y: 2}],
            label: "Asia",
            backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
            fill: false
          }, { 
            data: [{x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 1}, {x: 3, y: 1}],
            label: "Europe",
            backgroundColor: "#3cba9f",
            fill: false
          }, { 
            data: [{x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 1}, {x: 3, y: 1}],
            label: "Latin America",
            backgroundColor: "#e8c3b9",
            fill: false
          }, { 
            data: [{x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 1}, {x: 3, y: 1}],
            label: "North America",
            backgroundColor: "#c45850",
            fill: false
          }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        legend: { display: false },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
        },
        responsive: false, 
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {source: 'data'}
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?